# Pandas columnwise merge rows which satisfy condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
0     1     2     ...   20
data  NaN   2010  ...   2020
id    Name  val   ...   val
1     Tom   55    ...   67
2     Jerry 45    ...   78
.
.
```

Now I am looking for row which contains id in any column and creating a mask like so:

```
mask = (df.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('id', case=False)).any(axis=1))
```

Now I want to column wise merge all the rows (separated by "_"), which come before `id` is found, like so:

```
0        1     2         ...   20
data_id  Name  2010_val  ...   2020_val
1        Tom   55        ...   67
2        Jerry 45        ...   78
.
.
```

Comment: There is only one `id` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes, only one id but it can be in any row or column

Comment: `val` is not before `2010` and `2020` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible order of values from back all values before `id` first processing values before `id` and then apped values after `id`:

```
df = df.iloc[::-1]

mask = (df.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('id', case=False)).any(axis=1))


m = mask.cumsum().gt(0)
df = pd.concat([df[m].agg(lambda x: '_'.join(x.dropna())).to_frame().T,
                df[~m]], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: @Ank - Maybe not understand it. so you need join values only before `id` rows? Is possible change data sample e.g. by add some new row and add expected output?